# finding all combinations of a list of any count

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to generate all combinations of items in a given list with an output of a given count. The inputs will be the list and the number of items in each returned combination. For example:

```
list = [a, b, c, d]
number of items in output: 2
```

returns:

```
[(a, b), (a, c), (a, d), (b, c), (b, d), (c, d)]
```

The same list with number of items in output: 3

returns:

```
[(a, b, c), (a, b, d), (a, c, d), (b, c, d)]
```

note that (a, b) == (b, a) etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You know, I haven't been a daily reader of SO in a long time, but I thought the rule was that to receive assistance, question-askers have to show a little effort. Otherwise, we're building stuff for people instead of sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 3))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` has a [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function as well as [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).